# Custom UIBarButtonItem in UISplitViewController doesn't respond to clicks (iPhone)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm trying to customize the appearance of a `UIBarButtonItem` on a `UISplitViewController` divided into two `UINavigationController`'s (the detail and master views), but keep hitting a brick wall. I first followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852593/uisplitviewcontroller-displaymodebuttonitem), but have been unable to achieve the desired results.

If if I implement the back button in the `viewDidLoad` method of my Detail View Controller in this way:

```
if let svc = splitViewController {
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = svc.displayModeButtonItem()
}
```

I get the default 'Back' button that navigates back to Master View controller. But if I try to customize the button using the following code:

```
    if let svc = splitViewController {
        let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(
            image: UIImage(named: "magnifying-glass"),
            style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
            target: svc.displayModeButtonItem().target,
            action: svc.displayModeButtonItem().action
        )

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchButton
    }
```

I get the desired icon in the navbar but it does nothing when clicked. I've debugged the action and target in the console and for both the action is "_triggerDisplayModeAction:" and the controller is an instance of the UISplitViewController.

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: are the instances of UISplitViewController same ?

Comment: can you share code inside displayModeButtonItem() method

Comment: the SplitViewController hasn't been subclassed so it's the default implementation of SplitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()

Comment: are you sure, that navigationItem belongs to the right controller? that is the only part of you snippet we don't have any idea about.  be careful and check it  in prepareForSeque somewhere in you implementation of master view controller. the creation of your custom button seems to be  OK. it is common mistake, i can see a lot of time, that people believe that they are working with the right instance ...
navigationItem belongs to navigation bar and navigation bar to some navigation controller, not to your detail view controller

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to create and use your custom UIBarButtonItem in prepareForSeque in master view controller. split view controller by default will create new instance of your detail view controller!!! ignore the part with iPhone ios7support, that is another story :-) https://github.com/op183/MasterDetailDemo

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow() {
            let object = objects[indexPath.row] as String
            if let navController = (segue.destinationViewController as? UINavigationController) {
                let controller = navController.topViewController as DetailViewController
                controller.detailItem = object
                let defaultBarButton = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
                let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(
                    image: UIImage(named: "magnifying-glass"),
                    style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain,
                    target: defaultBarButton.target,
                    action: defaultBarButton.action
                )
                controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = searchButton
                controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
            } else {

                // iPhone ios7support
                (segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController).detailItem = object
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight about split view controller behavior, but I'm still having the same issue after making the adjustment you suggested. The button is there but doesn't link back

Comment: let share you code via github, if you want. it is interesting for me, because i use 'custom' UIBarButtonItem frequently  and it seems, that code from your snippet in question seems to be just fine.

Comment: it's being set up here: https://github.com/kellanburket/ravelry/blob/master/ravelry/LoaderImageController.swift

Comment: it is a "little bit" hard to follow, but
a) prepareSegue  with custom button should be implemented in CategorySearchController and type of segue to his 'detail' should be show detail, not show.

Comment: send me a screenshot, where is your custom button

Comment: It was reachable. That's why I was able to log it to the Xcode console. I recently went to a navigation view since it doesn't seem to have this problem