# how to show barButtonItem when using splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode: in iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

My App's structure likes this:

```
UISplitViewController:

the master:NavigationController1->UITableViewController

the detail:NavigationController2->UIWebViewController
```

I want to show the barButtonItem when the view goes on portrait mode on iPad
and I know how to realize it in iOS7 by willHideViewController:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc{
        barButtonItem.title = @"Course";
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem{
    if (barButtonItem == self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem) {
         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
```

However, this method is deprecated in iOS 8, and i tried to use:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode{
    if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = svc.displayModeButtonItem;
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
```

This method only works when the display mode changes but not when the app first starts with a portrait orientation. 
So how to show barButtonItem when loading the app first time with a portrait orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the bar button when your view controller shows up:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.splitViewController.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden)
    {
        UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        barButtonItem.title = @"Show master";
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    }
}
```

This will only add the button when the master is currently hidden.

Comment: thanks, it works but there is a symbol "<" beside the title "Show master".

Comment: @gao6708 The best solution i found for this is, if you add your own UIBarButtonItem to the Navigation Bar. See: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/26197227/4150105](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26197227/4150105) This is in Swift, but you should be able to translate it easily. Remember to setup the same button in `splitViewController:willChangeToDisplayMode:`

Comment: thanks, get it!  `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course" style:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.style target:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.target action:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.action];`

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if (self.splitViewController.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden){
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course" style:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.style target:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.target action:self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem.action];
    }
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode{
    if (displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Course" style:svc.displayModeButtonItem.style target:svc.displayModeButtonItem.target action:svc.displayModeButtonItem.action];
    }else{
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    }
}
```